# Converting multiple Markdown files to EPUB with Pandoc in C#

Tags: c#, pandoc, epub

I use this code to get the Epub file:

```
        string processName = "pandoc.exe";
        string arguments = "markdown-sample.md -o mybook.epub";

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = processName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true
        };

        var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

But I can not convert the folder with Markdown files. How is done in the example.[enter link description here](https://pandoc.org/epub.html#a-real-book)

```
 string arguments = @"pandoc -o progit.epub"
                  + @"title.txt \"
                  + @"01-introduction/01-chapter1.markdown \"
                  + @"02-git-basics/01-chapter2.markdown \"
                  + @"03-git-branching/01-chapter3.markdown \"
                  + @"04-git-server/01-chapter4.markdown \"
                  + @"05-distributed-git/01-chapter5.markdown \"
                  + @"06-git-tools/01-chapter6.markdown \"
                  + @"07-customizing-git/01-chapter7.markdown \"
                  + @"08-git-and-other-scms/01-chapter8.markdown \"
                  + @"09-git-internals/01-chapter9.markdown";
```

How converting the folder with Markdown files to EPUB with Pandoc in C# ?

And:
How changing directories in Pandoc using C# ?

```
string puth = @"cd progit/en";
```

dont work.

Comment: Change `string arguments = @"pandoc -o progit.epub"` to `string arguments = @"pandoc -o progit.epub "` (add a space, otherwise, you'll get `progit.epubtitle.txt` etc...)

Comment: The backslash `\\` as line continue character is not valid for Windows. It is not needed here, because you are building one string anyhow.